# can't download blender 2.8 zip file

Tags: add-on, file-format

I can't download blender 2.8 zip file.I tried to download on blender website,but they show us blender msi file not zip file

Answer (score 2):

https://www.blender.org/download/[image]

You have to click on the thing to get download options.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/80974/arthur-blaquart. thank you

Comment: Please mark this as an answer for the post, thanks :)